# How to have a Game Object remove itself from a list? (Unity3d)

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, gameobject

OK so basically I have a list that keeps track of all the enemies in the scene. I am using the list primarily so I can have each enemy check other enemies positions so they don't end up on the same spot. When ever an enemy is created it will add itself to a list, but I need the enemy to remove itself once it's killed. I tried what I have in the code below but it throws me an error (ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range).

```
void Start () 
{
    Manager.EnemyList.Add(this.gameObject);
    ListSpot = Manager.EnemyList.Count; 
}

//Kills the enemy
public void Kill()
{
    Manager.EnemyList.RemoveAt(ListSpot);
    Destroy(this.gameObject);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `Manager.EnemyList.Remove(this.gameObject)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a list from the **System.Collections.Generic** namespace, then you can just call Add and Remove with the instance of the object. It will use the hash functions of the instance to do its thing.

```
List<GameObject> enemies = new List<GameObject>();
enemies.Add(enemy1);
enemies.Remove(enemy1);
```

**Edit**: your solution throws the exception because the index starts by 0 and count will always begin to count at 1. if you add the first element its position is 0, but the count is 1.

Comment: but, most of the times, we want list to store something, while delleteing them, we might not have that gameobject..

Comment: If you need things outside the lifecycle of monobehaviours and gameobjects you can now use a static initialization method like the good old static main method using this attribute: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethodAttribute.html